# How can I dynamically link to a directory that doesn't exist (yet)?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, basic-msi

I have an InstallScript project that I'm looking at manually recreating as a Basic MSI project. For the InstallScript project, we have several components that utilize dynamic file linking, and link to a location specified in a path variable.

However, when I attempt to do this in the Basic MSI project, I receive an error: "The folder name you have entered is not a valid folder name on your system." This is completely correct - the specified directories don't exist, but they will be created at build time, before the installer is compiled. The InstallScript project seemed to have no qualms about dynamically linking to a directory that does not currently exist. The Basic MSI refuses to do it.

Is there any way to link to directories that don't exist (yet)? Do I need to create dummy folders in these locations to appease InstallShield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the I endorse dynamic linking at all,  but if you must, just create the empty directory where the build automation will create it and then setup your dynamic links.  ( Design by contract. )

Course that's the problem with dynamic file linking...... there isn't much of a contract as compared to actually describing which files get installed where.   YMMV.